# SQL retrieve results based on String matching from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables say A and B. A has many columns like Date, Customer, Price, typedesc etc. B has only one column typedesc. I want to retrieve rows in A whose typedesc is in B. So I wrote

```
select * from A where typedesc in (select typedesc from B)
```

I got 0 rows in result. So i tried

```
select A.* from A inner join B on A.typedesc=B.typedesc
```

Still I am getting 0 rows in result

I manually checked the typedesc column in both tables, there are matching entries. typedesc contains strings and it is of type varchar2

Here are the sample tables

A

```
DATE       CUSTOMER      TYPEDESC      SKU        PRICE
02/01/2013    4567     CREAM CORDIALS   1234       23
03/01/2013    3256     U.S. BRANDY      3322       10.5
```

B

```
TYPEDESC

CREAM CORDIALS
FIRE WHISKY
```

Comment: your queries should work just fine. can you give sample records?

Comment: @JW웃 added table samples

Comment: your query should work: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93a4d/1 please check the records if there are extra spaces.

Comment: Thanks JW, it was the matter of spacing. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the TRIM function before comparison to avoid the mismatch due to extra spaces.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The spacing seems to be correct when I see in output. But as you said, it needed trim.

Comment: do not use `TRIM()` when joining table since it will kill the indexes if you have one. The best way to do is to update the record by trimming it eg. `UPDATE B SET TYPEDESC = TRIM(TYPEDESC)`, so will not end up joining like this `A.typedesc=TRIM(B.typedesc)` -- bad.